# SQL Server 2012 cannot copy Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working with SQL server 2012. I want to copy a database along with all the data. I just want to create a dev DB.

I know SQL Server 2012 has a `Copy Database...` wizard. But when I run that wizard, I get an error on the last step:

[image]

On error, it tells me that error log in inside a text file on the shown path. When I go to that path, there is no such file there.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you want to do a backup not a copy.

Comment: May be you need to raise this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I tried backup and then restore with a different name as well. But it gave similar results. I got error while restoring. But I couldn't find the error log file.

Comment: What does the sql server log and the event log say?

Comment: I have posted another alternative solution that worked for me. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do it the other way. I created an empty DB and used import wizard to import all the data and the schemas. This worked without any error. But I still don't know why the Copy Wizard didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check event log, If you use Backup and Restore mode, change it to detach and attach mode.

Answer (score 0):

The file path is relative to the server. This is because the copy database wizard (CDW) creates a SQL Agent job to do the work. The file is the execution log for the agent job.